# Firebase to Tableview issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, database-design

I am having issues getting my data from firebase to show on my TableView. I only want the vin number to display on the table view. Right now i am either getting cells that display "nil", or nothing in the cells.

My goal is to have each cell display the Vin Number.

Can someone take a look and let me know where i have an issue?

Thanks!!!
Alex

here is what my firebase database looks like

child --Vehicles

child--5UXKR0C34H0X82785

child-- VehicleInfo
then under the "vehicle Info" child it displays these three fields

make:"toyota"

model:"corolla"

VinNumber: "5UXKR0C34H0X82785"

Here is my Vehicle model class

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

struct VehicleModel {
var Make: String?
var Model: String?
var VinNumber: String?

init(Make: String?, Model: String?, VinNumber: String?){
    self.Make = Make
    self.Model = Model
    self.VinNumber = VinNumber
}

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    VinNumber = snapshotValue["VinNumber"] as? String
    Make = snapshotValue["Make"] as? String
    Model = snapshotValue["Model"] as? String
  }
}
```

Here is my view controller code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
class InventoryTableViewController: UITableViewController{


    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!
    var userList = [VehicleModel]()

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView?.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
    "cellId")
    fetchUsers()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return userList.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Set cell contents
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: 
indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let eachvehicle = userList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(String(describing: eachvehicle.VinNumber))"
    return cell
}

func fetchUsers(){
            refHandle = ref.child("Vehicles").observe(.childAdded, with: { 
(snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print(dictionary)
            let VinNumber = dictionary["VinNumber"]
            let Make = dictionary["Make"]
            let Model = dictionary["Model"]
            self.userList.insert(VehicleModel(Make: Make as? String, Model: 
Model as? String, VinNumber:         VinNumber as? String), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()              
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Also, I am having issues displaying the make and model of the selected cell in another view controller connected by a segue. I have attempted to set up passing the values but can not get it to work.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"AdditionalInfoViewController") as! AdditionalInfoViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAdditionalInfo", sender: self)
        let row = indexPath.row
        print("working so far ")

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
    makeToPass = currentCell.Model
    modelToPass = currentCell.Make      
} 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toMapView" {
        var viewController = segue.destination as! AdditionalInfoViewController
        viewController.makeToPass = makeValueToPass
        viewController.modelToPass = modelValueToPass            

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is your data structure, right?

```
Vehicles: {
   5UXKR0C34H0X82785: {
        VehicleInfo: {
            make:"toyota",
            model:"corolla",
            VinNumber: "5UXKR0C34H0X82785"
        }
    }
}
```

Which means in order to access the data under `VehicleInfo`, you need to specify that location. There are a few ways you can do this, but one of them would be using `childSnapshot(forPath:)`

```
func fetchUsers(){
            refHandle = ref.child("Vehicles").observe(.childAdded, with: { 
(snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "VehicleInfo").value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print(dictionary)
            let VinNumber = dictionary["VinNumber"]
            let Make = dictionary["Make"]
            let Model = dictionary["Model"]
            self.userList.insert(VehicleModel(Make: Make as? String, Model: 
Model as? String, VinNumber:         VinNumber as? String), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()              
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped! As an aside, keep in mind that if you have other data under the push Ids under `Vehicles` besides `VehicleInfo`, then you are downloading that data whenever a new vehicle is added whether or not you are using the data besides `VehicleInfo`. If there is other data under, say, the child `5UXKR0C34H0X82785` besides `VehicleInfo`, then you may want to rethink how the listener is triggered or how the database is structured so that you're only downloading the data you need.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that as well. I will definitely look at the database to see if i can restructure it. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hey Jen, i just updated this thread with another related issue with the tableview and my data setup. If you or anyone else has a second, could you check it out? Thanks

Comment: A separate issue should be a separate question. That will make it easier to find the right answer if other people have the same question.

Comment: Rodger that. Just posted. Link below so everyone looking at this in the future can find it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475879/passing-firebase-data-from-tableview-to-viewcontroller

Comment: @JenPerson I'm afraid you've used uppercased key, where Alex has all lowercase (`make` in the database vs `"Make"` in the DataSnapshot dictionary), which might have introduced the confusion.